# PowerApps LookUp of a Person or Group type from Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, syntax, powerapps

I have a field that is a combobox filled with names that is auto-populated(defaultselectedItems) with the name of the user of the PowerApp using Office365User.MyProfileV2().displayName. This name can be found in a sharepoint list I can access through a lookup function, my goal is to lookup the name of the value(which is a type person or group) and find the corresponding title value and set it to the defaultSelectedItems of another combobox, if found, and if not it should just be a blank value. My most likely problem is with the syntax, but I have tried other sources to look for a correction with no success. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reference a combobox people picker and grab their Title with the below setup:

Combobox is a People Picker. If you have this already set up it can be skipped:
Item = `Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:ComboBox.SearchText,top:10})`

The next one can be a text input or label to reference:
Text = `ComboBox.Selected.JobTitle`